# Jquery Cookies Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I'm trying to use jquery cookies to store the state of a tree menu between page loads, for some reason the below code does not seem to create a cookie inside the switch statement. Using the cookie code outside of the switch statement works fine. I'm not too great with JS so it could be a simple issue with my switch,

```
intImage = 2;
var catCookie = jQuery.cookie('catCookie');


if(catCookie == 'left')
{
intImage = 1;
};

if(catCookie == 'down')
{
intImage = 2;
};


function swapImage() {
switch (intImage) {
 case 1:
    intImage = 2
 document.getElementById(".giftarrow").src = "http://www.domain.com/left-arrow.png";
 jQuery.cookie('catCookie', 'left')

return(false);
case 2:

   intImage = 1
 document.getElementById(".giftarrow").src = "http://www.domain.com/down-arrow.png";
 jQuery.cookie('catCookie', 'down')
 return(false);
 }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you are already using jquery, why use `document.getElementById(".giftarrow")` syntax instead of just `$("giftarrow)`? Won't the latter one be much cooler ?

Comment: I was just going to use standard js in the original version, will be cleaning syntax once its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some semicolons:

```
switch (intImage) {

 case 1:
    intImage = 2;
    $('.giftarrow').attr('src', 'http://www.gracecole.co.uk/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/images/left-arrow.png');
    jQuery.cookie('catCookie', 'left');
    return(false);

 case 2:
    intImage = 1;
    $('.giftarrow').attr('src','http://www.gracecole.co.uk/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/images/down-arrow.png');
    jQuery.cookie('catCookie', 'down');
    return(false);
 }
```